# long exact sequence of homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

In the long exact sequence $\cdots \to \tilde{H} (A) \to \tilde{H}(X) \to H(X, A) \to \cdots$, why isn’t the third homology in the sequence given in a reduced homology?

Also I am wondering why the order is specifically $A\to X\to (X, A)$. Is there any intuitive motivation behind it?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you? If yes, it would be appreciated if you accept either one.

Comment: Thanks, I've been slowly going over the materials related to that. I can't say that I have completely digested this material, but for sure I'll do that at the end of studying this part.

Comment: No worries, take your time! You are not forced to accept anyway, it's totally fine to leave it as unanswered if you'd like to leave an opportunity for others to answer. Feel free to ask if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your second question is an algebraic one. Let $X$ be a top. space and $A\subset X$ a subspace. Let $(C_\bullet(X),\partial_\bullet)$ be a chain complex. The relative chaingroup $C_n(X,A)$ is defined as the quotient $$ C_n(X,A):= C_n(X)\big/C_n(A)$$

Observe that the differential $\partial_\bullet$ takes $$C_\bullet(A)\to C_{\bullet-1}(A)$$ which then induces a complex of quotients $$\cdots \to C_n(X,A)\to C_{n-1}(X,A)\to C_{n-2}(X,A) \to \cdots$$

Which gives rise to a short exact sequence $$0\to C_n(A)\xrightarrow{i} C_n(X)\xrightarrow{p} C_n(X,A) \to 0 \quad (*)$$ where $i$ is the inclusion and $p$ the quotient map. Since the differential $\partial_\bullet$ is part of each of the chain complexes $$C_\bullet(A), C_\bullet(X), C_\bullet(X,A)$$ we can interpret $(*)$ as a *short exact sequence of chain complexes* for which you'll get the homology groups $H_n(-)$ of the respective complexes  $C_\bullet(A), C_\bullet(X), C_\bullet(X,A)$ by the snake lemma.

The snake lemma provides the long exact homology sequence you are looking at $$\cdots H_{n}(A) \to H_{n}(X) \to H_{n}(X,A) \xrightarrow{\rho} H_{n-1}(A)\to \cdots$$ where $\rho$ denotes the connecting map.

So generally speaking, the sequence $$H_n(A)\to H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)$$ comes from the short exact sequence $(*)$ and applying the snake lemma to get the long exact sequence of the respective homology groups.

Answer (score 3):

The answer of both questions are given by the natural isomorphism (when (X,A) is a good pair, it means $A$ is a closed subspace which is a deformation retract of some neighbourhood in $X$.)
$$H_n(X,A)\cong {\overset{\sim}{H}}_n(X/A).$$ The proof of this fact is a consequence of excision, the proof can be found in Hatcher's book Prop. 2.22.

Thus relative homology groups are really reduced homology groups, and the long exact sequence can be obtained applying the reduced homology functor to the sequence

$$A\to X\to X/A.$$